# Undefined not assignable to user type

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I am receiving the following error

```
error TS2322: Type 'MyConfig| undefined' is not assignable to type 'MyConfig'.
Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'MyConfig'.
```

From a component we can call `MyAppComponent` which has the following Input variables

```
  @Input() userInfoInput?: UserInfo;

  @Input() MyConfigInput?: MyConfig;
```

UserInfo is an interface model shown below

```
export interface UserInfo{
   [key: string]: any;
   firstName: string | undefined;
   middleName: string | undefined;
   lastName: string | undefined;
 }
```

and MyConfig is a class

```
export class MyConfig{
  private _name!: string;
  private _description!: string;
  private _version!: string;
  private _dateFormat!: string;
  private _maxContentLength!: number;

  constructor(
     name: string,
     description: string,
     version: string,
     dateFormat: string,
     maxContentLength: number,
     ) {
     this.name = name;
     this.description = description;
     this.version = version;
     this.dateFormat = dateFormat;
     this.maxContentLength = maxContentLength;
   }
```

In the currently functional code the `@Input` variables are decorated with the non-null assertion operator `!` since I cannot explicitly define them in the constructor. I would like to instead use `?` / `MyConfigInput : MyConfig | undefined`, but I am getting this error that I cannot assign undefined to these types. I have supplied other types I have created as `@Input` into this component to test and they do not report the same error. So I guess I am missing some intuition as to why I cannot assign `undefined` to these types in particular.

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why do you want to change `MyConfigInput` to be possibly undefined?

Comment: From what I understand until an actual value for MyConfigInput is loaded in, it is undefined. MyConfigInput may be undefined coming from the DOM from what I understand. So using `!` is just tricking the compiler to compile, if that makes sense? These inputs are coming from another component which can change configuration and users at run-time